# Delphi DataSnap framework adding stuff to JSON message

Tags: delphi, json, rest, datasnap

I'm working with a Delphi XE DataSnap REST server and trying to return a JSON serialized object.  The result that my method is returning to the client looks like this:

```
{"type":"ServerMethodsUnit1.TJSONIssue",
 "id":1,
 "fields":{
           "FIssueNo":90210,
           "FTitle":"Beverly Hills...that''s where I want to be",
           "FKind":"Wishlist"
          }
}
```

Well formed JSON.

The problem is that when the message is received by the client, there's a bunch of stuff added to it and it looks like this:

```
{"result": ["{\"type\":\"ServerMethodsUnit1.TJSONIssue\",
              \"id\":1,
              \"fields\":{
                          \"FIssueNo\":90210,
                          \"FTitle\":\"Beverly Hills...that's where I want to be\",
                          \"FKind\":\"Wishlist\"}
             }
            "
           ]
}
```

I'm getting a bunch of backslash characters and that `"result"` tag in front.

I was wondering if anybody knows why I'm getting this extra stuff and how to get rid of it.

Comment: It looks like you are doing a double JSON?  The escape characters (the backslash) is standard for JSON strings.

Answer (score 7):

To get rid of `"result"` tag you should use `OnFormatResult` event of `TDSHTTPWebDispatcher`. Especialy the value `Handled`. The value of `Handled` is `false` by default. If set to `true`, then the result passed to the user will not be wrapped in a `"result"` JSON object. If it is false, then it will be wrapped in this object.

Example. I have code like this:

```
function TServerMethods1.EchoStringJSON(Value: string): TJSONObject;
var
  JSONObj : TJSONObject;
begin
  JSONObj := TJSONObject.Create;
  JSONObj.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('name',Value));
  result := JSONObj;
end;
```

REST service response looks like this: `{"result":[{"name":"asdfasdf"}]}`

I add `Handled := true;`:

```
procedure TWebModule1.DSHTTPWebDispatcher1FormatResult(Sender: TObject;
  var ResultVal: TJSONValue; const Command: TDBXCommand; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Handled := true;
end;
```

REST service response looks like this:`[{"name":"asdfasdf"}]`.

Still have `"[]"`. So I add some additional code:

```
procedure TWebModule1.DSHTTPWebDispatcher1FormatResult(Sender: TObject;
  var ResultVal: TJSONValue; const Command: TDBXCommand; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  Aux: TJSONValue;
begin
  //remove [] element
  Aux := ResultVal;
  ResultVal := TJSONArray(Aux).Items[0];
  TJSONArray(Aux).Remove(0);
  Aux.Free;
  //we do not need "result" tag
  Handled := true;
end;
```

Now result looks like:`{"name":"asdfasdf"}`

PS. The answer was found here: [section FormatResult Event for REST Responses](http://mathewdelong.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/delphilive-2011-recap/).

Answer (score 4):

The JSON that you have posted rapresent a result for a remote method that returns a string, not a JSONObject.
The correct way to return a JSONObject should be the following (not compiled/tested):

```
function TMyRemote.GetSomething: TJSONValue;
begin
  Result := TJSONObject.Create;
  Result.Add("Name","Daniele Teti"); //used the overloaded version of add (string, string)
end;
```

Now the json should be correct.
The RESULT element in the result string is as-designed. You can read the first element of the result array and get your original JSONObject.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a Delphi Desktop as a client ? if Yes maybe you can try other return from your method because Delphi make a automatically conversion of any return type to JSON

for example : 
return a DBXReader will be converted to a JSON Type

In case you have other Client (php, java, flex) I cant to help you.
I have the same problem ..I created a method to receive a JSONObject as parameter and I did a simples PHP code to invoke this method... I created a object class and pass it ..in the server it cant convert JSONObject to Object ...the error happens when UnMarshall execute..

My tests just work with primitive types !